# keeping checkbox status in rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have some  check-boxes in my rails application the code is below

```
<%= check_box_tag "audio_ids[]",audio.id ,nil,class: "song"%>
<%= check_box_tag "audio_ids[]",audio.id ,nil,class: "song"%>
<%= check_box_tag "audio_ids[]",audio.id ,nil,class: "song"%>
<button class="btn btn-warning">play all</button>

<script>
function handleButtonClick(button){
if ($(button).text().match("Check all")){
$(":checkbox").prop("checked", true)
} else {
$(":checkbox").prop("checked", false)
};
updateButtonStatus();
}

function updateButtonStatus(){
var allChecked = $(":checkbox").length === $(":checkbox:checked").length;
$("button").text(allChecked? "Uncheck all" : "Check all");
}

function updateCookie(){
var elementValues = {};
$(":checkbox").each(function(){
elementValues[this.id] = this.checked;
});

elementValues["buttonText"] = $("button").text();
$.cookie('elementValues', elementValues, { expires: 7, path: '/' })
}

function repopulateFormELements(){
var elementValues = $.cookie('elementValues');
if(elementValues){
Object.keys(elementValues).forEach(function(element) {
var checked = elementValues[element];
$("#" + element).prop('checked', checked);
});

$("button").text(elementValues["buttonText"])
}
}

$(":checkbox").on("change", function(){
updateButtonStatus();
updateCookie();
});

$("button").on("click", function() {
handleButtonClick(this);
updateCookie();
});


$.cookie.json = true;
repopulateFormELements();
</script>
```

They keep their status while just refreshing the page but whenever i came from different page they lost their status but when I check this code separately it works but not with rails , what is the problem with this code and what I have to do?